# How can I map "&" as "&amp;" in a dynamically generated XML file in a Smarty template?

Tags: php, xml, smarty

I have an xml file that has a `xmlParseEntityRef: no name` error.
I know that it is caused by the *&* symbol and removing or replacing it with `&amp;` will do the trick. Problem is this xml file is dynamically generated and is usually very large (>5MB).

I was playing with defining this as a doctype entity to no avail. Any ideas?

---

Thanks for all the feedback. I completely agree with all of you.
However as I need a quick solution to this issue, I resulted to finding a solution on the Smarty template side of things.

I found that I can redirect the value of a variable to a php function like so:

```
{$foo|htmlentities}
```

Reference is [here] (http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=60401)

Problem solved!

I've updated this question just in case somebody has a similar problem.

Comment: Can't you fix the "real" problem? E.g replacing the illegal characters before outputing the XML?

Comment: I actually answered my own question. Kindly check it, in case you have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to say it, but you need to fix the app the generates it. What it's generating is NOT XML.

You could probably also get by with using something like `sed` to pre-process the file, but that's just evil.

Comment: This gets a little more complicated then. The data holder for the content is a complicated assoc array that is being passed on a smarty template to be rendered.

Answer (score 1):

Any program that purports to generate XML has a responsibility to make that XML well-formed. If the program is generating garbage, fix it or throw it out.